# How to search orders using a purchase order number

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, increment-id

I need to be able to filter orders by searching the purchase order number from the order. Is this possible?

Comment: please explain where are you want to use ?

Comment: When an invoice is generated using the purchase order payment method, the customer inputs their 'purchase order number' this number is then displayed on the invoice as a reference to the purchase order. I need to be able to search the generated invoices for these numbers. I hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to the admin panel and click Sales->Orders. In this grid you can filter by Order No. (this is called increment_id in the sales_flat_order table)

Also if you want to search using mysql:

```
Select * from sales_flat_order where increment_id = 'your_order_increment_id';
```

or

```
Select * from sales_flat_order where increment_id in ('your_order_increment_id', 'other_increment_id', 'more');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter order by the **Purchase Order Number (i.e., Purchase Order Payment method)**

The Payment method and Purchase Order number will be saved in `sales_flat_order_payment`

Try below code

```
<?php
    $purchaseOrderNumber = '12';
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $orders->getSelect()->join(
        array('payment' => $orders->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_payment')),
        'payment.parent_id = main_table.entity_id',
        array()
    );
    $orders->addFieldToFilter('method','purchaseorder');
    $orders->addFieldToFilter('po_number',array('like' => '%'.$purchaseOrderNumber.'%'));

    print_r($orders->getData());
?>
```

**Note:** The above code will only For native Purchase order payment method

Comment: hello, thank you for your help but forgive me for my ignorance, what do I do with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using native PO functionality or is it from an extension? In any event, the PO number attribute - if it's a `sales_order` attribute - can be used to filter as follows:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('po_number', '1234567');
```

Comment: This has me thinking, and maybe I'll start a new question, but is this fundamentally any different than using `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load('1234567', 'po_number')`?

Comment: Some object setup stuff may be skipped (which could be good or bad). Really using this as an example in case OP wants to search for multiples.